# Is $\mathbb{Z_2} \cong \{-1,+1\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is  $\mathbb{Z_2}  \cong \{-1,+1\}$ ? Yes/No

This   doubt  basically arose  when  I was  solving this  problem:

$1.$${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) / H \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$  where $ H $ is the subgroup of all matrices  in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with positive  determinant

$2.$ ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) /{\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{R})  \cong \{-1,+1\}$

I think both  $1$ and $2$  look the same  to me.

Comment: 1. does not make any sense, since $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. What did you really mean to write ?

Comment: @GreginGre  i have  edits  its

Comment: You can prove that they're isomorphic (remember to carefully consider the group operation)

Comment: The ansewr to 1 is yes. The function that maps a matrix to the sign of its determinant is a homomorphism and its kernel is $H$. The answer to 2 is no; there are infinitely (uncountably) many cosets of $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$. In fact, the determinant is a homomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^{\times}$ and its kernel is $SL_n(\mathbb R)$. Therefore $GL_n(\mathbb R) / SL_n(\mathbb R) \cong \mathbb R^{\times}$.

Comment: What Bungo said is right: $GL_n(\mathbb R)/SL_n(\mathbb R) \cong \mathbb R^\times = (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. However, $GL_n(\mathbb Z)/SL_n(\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z^\times = \{-1,1\}$, which must be what you meant in 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (to your first, titular question), if the group $\{-1, 1\}$ has the operation given by $$\begin{array}{c|cc} \times & 1 & -1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 1\end{array}.$$ Please specify the operation in future.

---

*NB:* Your $2$ is wrong though. See [the comment by @Bungo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404624/is-mathbbz-2-cong-1-1/3404630#comment7002977_3404624) above.

Comment: Well, to be fair, there is only one operation on that set which makes it a 2-element group.

Answer (score 2):

It is every easy to show that all groups with two elements are isomorphic. Also, all  rings with identity and with two elements are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $-1$ generates $\{-1,1\}$.